# Problem with premmision setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

I have try run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but get error:
[image]

I have set premmision for var and pub folder:

```
chmod 777 var/cache -R
chmod 777 var -R
chmod 777 pub -R
chmod 777 pub/media -R
```

Still no work.

Comment: did you check the ownership group of your magento folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

From magento root directory

```
chown -R www-data .
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

[see more](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)